# How to create a simple side nav with drop down items

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple side nav that has some subitems. I think I've figured out how to do it, but I'm not sure if this is the best way.

```
<ul>
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li class="dropdown">Item 2
  <ul class="hidden">
    <li>Item 2 - subitem1</li>
    <li>Item 2 - subitem2</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li class="dropdown">Item 4
  <ul class="hidden">
    <li>Item 4 - subitem1</li>
    <li>Item 4 - subitem2</li>
    <li>Item 4 - subitem3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
```

```
<style>
  ul.hidden {
    display:none;
  }  
</style>

<script>
  $(function() {
   $('.dropdown').click(function(){
    $('.hidden').hide();
    $(this).find('.hidden').toggle();
   });
  });  
</script>
```

Comment: I suggest you check out [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), its a css framework that make creating website super easy. Here is a link to what you are trying to achieve with `Boostrap` [Side nav with drop down](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/admin-side-menu)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using something like Bootstrap, (it's overkill for what I need) but I did find a really good example of a side nav with sub items on [Cody House](https://codyhouse.co/gem/secondary-expandable-navigation/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS if you wish - on .hidden:action display:block;

Your JS is currently hiding something that is already hidden by css -- then finding all the instances of .hidden(which there are two).  You would need a foreach loop to toggle each of the dropdowns - then you would also need a release function to rehide the menu.

Bootstrap might give you a nice step in the right direction, or just use css for this.

`http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp`

`https://codepen.io/philhoyt/pen/ujHzd`